# Unexpected behaviour of coreutils 'sort'

Tags: sorting, locale, gnu-coreutils

I have encountered a strange behaviour of GNU coreutils *sort* on a machine running Red Hat Enterprise 7.1:

```
$ echo -e 'c11 2\nc1 1\nc11 4\nc1 3' | /usr/bin/sort -k1,1
c1 1
c11 2
c11 4
c1 3
```

I though it was a locale problem, and in fact:

```
$ echo -e 'c11 2\nc1 1\nc11 4\nc1 3' | LC_ALL="C" /usr/bin/sort -k1,1
c1 1
c1 3
c11 2
c11 4
```

However, I don't see why the system's locale (en_GB.UTF-8, see below) sorts in a way that - to me - makes little sense. It looks like it's ignoring the white spaces and sorting on the whole line.

I've then downloaded and compiled the **same** version of sort (coreutils 8.22), and surprisingly I get the behaviour that I expect **without** changing the locale:

```
$ echo -e 'c11 2\nc1 1\nc11 4\nc1 3' | /path/to/coreutils-8.22/src/sort -k1,1
c1 1
c1 3
c11 2
c11 4
```

My question is twofold:

1. Why does sort seem to ignore the field separator when the locale is en_GB.UTF-8?
2. Why does the compiled version behave differently?

---

Additional info:

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.

$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Maybe a bug in the installed version? Do you have an exact RPM package version string (like coreutils-8.22-15.el7_2.1.x86_64) ? Is there a system update available for it?

Comment: This is the RPM version: coreutils-8.22-12.el7_1.2.x86_64.rpm. It seems there's an update (https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2016-0177.html) but I don't think the fix is related.

Comment: I've just downloaded coreutils-8.22-12.el7_1.2.x86_64.rpm and built the binaries (after applying the patches) on a different machine where sort works as expected. This, again gives the wrong sorting. I think your hypothesis is right, it's probably a bug in the RPM version.